# Loop through XML elements in XmlDataSource in code behind

Tags: xpath, xmldatasource

I have an XmlDataSource and a GridView on my page. On the Page_Load event, I apply an XPath to filter the xml elements according to the input of the user, `LexiqueXmlDataSource.XPath = 'Some_XPath_here';` and it works just ok.

What I want is to access the elements that the XmlDataSource returns from codebehind after applying the XPath expression (and hence get their number).

I tried the `GetXmlDocument()` method but it returns the whole original Xml file rather than the filtered elements with XPath.

**EDIT:**

here is some code and the scenario I want:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

            string xpath = "/lexique/item[starts-with(@acronym, '" + filter + "')]";
            LexiqueXmlDataSource.XPath = xpath;

            // Here the XmlDataSource have filtered the xml elements to return to the GridView
            //I want to know how many element passed this filter using the XmlDataSource itself
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't `count(your_expression_here)` work?

Comment: I want to access the elements from the XmlDataSource, not access the xml file myself

Comment: I think is not clear... Do you want to access the selected nodes in the `Page_Load` event but without query the XML source again? Then you don't need an XPath expression. Retagging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I could come up with.

For the number of hits.  Use the GridView row count.  Indeed the GetXmlDocument.ChildNodes.Count always return the number of lexical items, not the number of hits whan the XPath expression is applied.

Test XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<lexique>
    <item acronym="WPF" value="Windows Presentation Foundation"/>
    <item acronym="SO" value="StackOverflow"/>
</lexique>
```

Minimalist ASP.net Page

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="xmlgrid.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="FilterLabel" runat="server" Text="Acronym starting with:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="FilterTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:XmlDataSource ID="LexiqueXmlDataSource" runat="server" DataFile="~/lexique.xml">
        </asp:XmlDataSource>
        <asp:GridView ID="LexiqueGrid" runat="server" AllowSorting="true" BorderStyle="Groove">
           <Columns>
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Acronym">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# XPath("/lexique/item/@acronym")%>
                 </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# XPath("/lexique/item/@value")%>
                 </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
           </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Label ID="Hits" runat="server" Text="Acronyms found"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Search" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind

```
Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim XPath As String

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterTextBox.Text) Then
            XPath = "/lexique/item"
        Else
            XPath = "/lexique/item[starts-with(@acronym, '" + FilterTextBox.Text + "')]"
        End If
        LexiqueXmlDataSource.XPath = XPath
        LexiqueXmlDataSource.DataBind()

        LexiqueGrid.DataSource = LexiqueXmlDataSource
        LexiqueGrid.DataBind()

        Hits.Text = "Selected " & LexiqueGrid.Rows.Count & " out of " &
            LexiqueXmlDataSource.GetXmlDocument.ChildNodes.Count & "Acronyms loaded."
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: That's what I call a solution :D thanx

Comment: Sorry but it seems you forgot to award the bounty ?

Comment: OH really? I marked your answer so it must get the bounty automatically no? how do I do it otherwise?

Comment: Actually, the standard way is to do it manually. Otherwise there are some rules called automatic award. [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) are the ins and outs about bounties.

Comment: Oh, I'm very very sorry, actually the bounty is awarded automatically is the best answer has at least 2 votes! I didn't award it manually and it didn't get awarded automatically? so who's got the points?

Comment: You must still have them I guess ;-)

Comment: Actually no, I just had a look at your reputation and the bounty was taken from you.

Comment: OK.  I understand.  If you don't award the bounty and the auto rules are not satisfied (which only gives *half* the points), then the bounty is lost for everybody.  See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55199/why-didnt-i-get-the-bounty) for the meta article. So don't worry, I learned something anyway.  Next time ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to know the number of returned elements.  Would the XPath expression 'count(Some_XPath_here)' not give this number of hits ?

Comment: I don't want to apply the XPath myself, I want to query the XmlDataSource for the elements that it filtered using the XPath expression

Comment: So I understand the XPath expression is a kind of black box and you focus on the resulting node set (supposedly returned from <asp:xmlDataSource tag in your page to which you apply a <asp:GridView format in that same page.  In the mean time, in the code behind you'd like to access the cardinality of the node-set.  You have invoked the GetXmlDocument and this has returned to you an XmlDataDocument.  Did you try thisXmlDataDocument.ChildNodes.count ?  I guess yes.  May be the XPath expression really returns the whole doc, and this where the pb lies.

Comment: @Alain Pannetier it's exactly the way you said, but when I query XmlDataDocument.ChildNodes.count it returns the number of nodes *in* the xml file and not the xml elements that the XmlDataSource returns when it apply the XPath expression

Comment: @Alain Pannetier the XPath expression works perfectly, because I can see the elements change in the GridView

Comment: Ooops, I had forgotten about your issue. Are you still interested ?

Comment: Could you post some of the XML you are using somewhere (e.g. pastebin) and if possible some of the relevant code ?

Answer (score 0):

> here is some code and the scenario I
>   want:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

            string xpath = "/lexique/item[starts-with(@acronym, '" + filter + "')]";
            LexiqueXmlDataSource.XPath = xpath;

            // Here the XmlDataSource have filtered the xml elements to return to the GridView
            //I want to know how many element passed this filter using the XmlDataSource itself
}
```

**Just use and evaluate this XPath expression**:

```
string xpath2 = "count(/lexique/item[starts-with(@acronym, '" + filter + "')])";
```